# Normal subgroups and abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

I am looking for a group which is not abelian but all of its subgroups are normal. Is there any example? Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone know a method to build more?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo:  If you chase the link to the [MathOverflow Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25307/groups-with-all-subgroups-normal) linked in Najib Idrissi's answer to the proposed duplicate, you will find the nonabelian groups of this kind (Hamiltonian groups) are classified and the description of the finite ones is fairly easy.

Answer (score 3):

The quaternions 
$$Q=\{\pm1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$$
is such a group. It has one subgroup of order two, namely $\{1,-1\}$, which is easily shown to be normal. All other proper subgroups are index two and therefore normal.

Comment: Very sorry, my bad, but nevertheless misleading title, and, for this case, not properly speaking a duplicate.